# Difference result by using sign and verify for signature

Tags: java, encryption, arrays, digital-signature, public-key

I tried to use private key to sign the message digest to generate the signature, and then use public key to verify the signature to get message digest. I want to compare with this two message digests, but i got a error about "java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 250 but was expecting 128".

When i tried to print out Arrays.toString(data2), its all 0.
I also tried to follow the link: [Verify the Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/vstep4.html)

```
 public void firstDigitalSignature() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, Throwable
 {

     //*Generate Message Digest1*
     byte[] buffer=null;
     buffer = new byte[(int) inputFile1.length()]; 
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile1);
     fis.read(buffer);
     MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); 
     messageDigest.update(buffer);
     digestBytes = messageDigest.digest();  
     //convert the byte to hex format method 2
     StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
     for(int i=0;i<digestBytes.length;i++){
         hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digestBytes[i]));
     }
     System.out.println("Message Digest-1: "+hexString.toString()); 

   //*Using private key to encrypt the image-Digital signauture1 *
     Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
     signature.initSign(privateKey);
     signature.update(digestBytes);
     encryptmd= signature.sign();
     StringBuffer hexString2 = new StringBuffer();
     for(int i=0;i<encryptmd.length;i++){
          hexString2.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & encryptmd[i]));
          x=hexString2.toString();
          File file = new File("c://Directroy111");
          if (!file.exists()) {  
             if (file.mkdir()) {
                 System.out.println("Doctor is created!");
             } else {
                 System.out.println("Failed to create Doctor!");
             }
      }
         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
         new FileWriter("C:\\Directroy111\\Digital Signature Doctor.txt"));
         out.write(x);
         out.close();
         this.copyImageFiles(sourceFile, destinationDir);
      }
          System.out.println("Message Digest Encrypted-1: "+hexString2.toString()+"\n");
   }


public void firstVerify() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, Throwable
{
//Generate Message Digest1 - Decrypt
String verifyfile= "c:\\Directroy111\\2.jpg";
File decryptfile= new File(verifyfile);
byte[] buffer2=null;
buffer2 = new byte[(int) decryptfile.length()]; //array type is integer, thats why we use int here
FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(decryptfile);
fis2.read(buffer2);
MessageDigest messageDigest2 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); 
messageDigest2.update(buffer2);
byte[] digestBytes2 = messageDigest2.digest();  
StringBuffer hexString22 = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=0;i<digestBytes2.length;i++){
  hexString22.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digestBytes2[i]));
}
System.out.println("Message Digest(Hash)-1(Decryption): "+hexString22.toString()); //System.out.println(hexString);

   //*******Decypt*************//
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
  signature.initVerify(publicKey);
  //FileReader read= new FileReader("C:\\TEMP1\\Doctor\\Digital Signature Doctor.txt");
  FileInputStream br2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Directroy111\\Digital Signature Doctor.txt");
 //BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(br2);
  //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(br2));
  byte[] data2=new byte[br2.available()];
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data2));
  br2.read(data2);
  br2.close();

  FileInputStream datafis=new FileInputStream("C:\\Directroy111\\Digital Signature Doctor.txt");
  BufferedInputStream bufin=new BufferedInputStream(datafis);
  byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];

  int len;
  while(bufin.available()!=0){
          len=bufin.read(buffer);
          signature.update(buffer,0,len);
      };
      bufin.close();
      System.out.println("111111");
      boolean decryptmd2= signature.verify(data2);
      System.out.println("signature verifies: " + decryptmd2);
      if(decryptmd2==false){
       str = String.valueOf(decryptmd2);
      System.out.println("Message Digest-1(Decryption): "+str);
      }else{
          System.out.println("1111");
      }

          //**Verify*
      if(str.equals(hexString22.toString())){
        System.out.println("Digital Signature-1 was not modified"+"\n");
      }else{

        System.out.println("ERROR!!!  Digital Signature-1 was modified"+"\n");
      }

}
```

Comment: Please add the code you used to generate the signature.

Comment: I just add the code of generate the signature.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple issues here.  First, the actual signing code should be included with your question as well.  Without being able to see the signing code, it's more difficult to debug the problem.  Check if your signing algorithm is the same as your verification algorithm (SHA256withRSA).

Next, if you're using the `SHA256withRSA` algorithm, you don't need to calculate a message digest first.  The algorithm will calculate it for you and sign the digest.  You just pass in the entire file to be signed.

In your verification step, you are updating the Signature object with the same file that you are saying is the signature.  Both files are `Digital Signature Doctor.txt`.  You should update the Signature object with the file to be signed, which I believe from your example is `2.jpg`.  Then when you call the `verify()` method, pass in the signature bytes.

Finally, you are misinterpreting the return value of `verify()`.  It returns a boolean.  It does not return the message digest or the original message.  When your code does `String.valueOf(decryptmd2)`, the value will either be "false" or "true".

I'm not sure why you are trying to compare the message digests.  Let's say you are sent a message with a signature signed by a private key corresponding to a public key that you trust.  IF the `verify()` method returns true, you can be sure that:

- the message was signed by that person
- the message you received is identical to the message that was signed

That should be sufficient for what you need.

Comment: Hi gtrig,
My propose is same as this image of receiver of this site: 
http://www.indicthreads.com/1480/what-are-digital-signatures-compute-and-verify-a-digital-signature-using-java/

Comment: SHA256withRSA with do the message digest for me?? i don't understand, but i checked api, it didn't say it will generate the message digest for me. Thats why i tried to generate the message digest.

Comment: If i changed `boolean decryptmd2= signature.verify(data2);` to `boolean decryptmd2= signature.verify(encryptmd);` it generates "true", and there is no error. 
"data2" is the message digest after i sign by private key and put this digital signature to txt file, and another one "encryptmd", which i didn't put it to the txt file, only put it to the variable, but i don't know why for "data2" is not work. "data2" and "encrypmd" both have same string (i already printed out to check).

Comment: `SHA256withRSA` will do the digest for you (a SHA256 digest will be performed on your data).  If you use `NONEwithRSA`, then you must provide a digest.  See the [signature algorithms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Signature) page for more info. Go back to the tutorial you listed in your original question.  There is also a tutorial on signing.  If you are getting "true" back from the verify method, it means that you were successful.  But in this case you are actually signing a digest of the digest and not the digest of the actual file.

Comment: I just want to make sure if it is correct i think.
first, i need to input the file (2.jpg), and then sign the file with private key to generate the digital signature, and then use public key to verify the digital signature to get message digest.

if SHA256withRSA will automatically generate the message digest, but how i can print out the content of that message digest??

I should not generate the message digest, but i still can not understand why the "data2" and "encryptmd" both are the same string, and one can not work.

Comment: Why do you need the digest?  You should only sign the 2.jpg file, which gives you a byte array, and then verify the signature.  You don't need the digest.  You can save the signature to a file much easier than you are doing.  Please re-read the Java tutorial completely to see how simple this process is.  You are making it much more complicated (and error-prone) than it needs to be.

Comment: when i do verify i need to compare two message digest. one is using public key to verify digital signature to get message digest-1, and then using hash function to calculate .jpg to generate the message digest-2. finally to compare message digest-1 and message digest-2. But if

Comment: I already delete the code of message digest.

`public void firstDigitalSignature() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, Throwable
{
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Directroy1\\2.jpg");
   ba = new byte[fis.available()];
   fis.read(ba);
   fis.close();
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    signature.initSign(privateKey);
    signature.update(ba);
    encryptmd= signature.sign();
    StringBuffer hexString2 = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<encryptmd.length;i++){
      hexString2.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & encryptmd[i]));`

Comment: But it still gave me the same error. 
`public void firstVerify() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, Throwable 
 {
    FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\Directroy111\\Digital Signature Doctor.txt");
   byte [] ba2 = new byte[fis2.available()];
   fis2.read(ba2);
   fis2.close();
   Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
      signature.initVerify(publicKey);
      signature.update(ba);
     boolean verify=signature.verify(ba2);
     System.out.println(verify);
   System.out.println("true or false: "+verify);     
     
     } `

Comment: once i replace  `boolean verify=signature.verify(ba2);` to  `boolean verify=signature.verify(ba2);`, the error is gone, and then print the "true".
BTW, i was looking for help for comments, but i didnt see how i can make the code to change line automatically.

Comment: You don't need the digest.  Also, the Signature.verify() method does NOT give message digests.  It only gives true/false.  Getting "true" is all you need to verify a signature of a message with a trusted public key.  Look at the Java tutorial that you linked to in your question.  Also look at the answer provided by GregS.  No message digests are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing gtrig's comments, here is a complete example showing signature creation and verification:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;

public class RSASignatureExample {

    private static int BUFSIZE = 8192;
    private PrivateKey privateKey;
    private PublicKey publicKey;

    public RSASignatureExample() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        privateKey = kp.getPrivate();
        publicKey = kp.getPublic();
    }

    private static void processData(File f, Signature s) throws Exception {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f), BUFSIZE);
        byte[] buf = new byte[BUFSIZE];
        int numRead;
        while ((numRead = bis.read(buf)) > 0) {
            s.update(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
        bis.close();
    }

    public byte[] sign(File fileToSign) throws Exception {
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signature.initSign(privateKey);
        processData(fileToSign, signature);
        return signature.sign();
    }

    public boolean verify(File fileToVerify, byte[] signatureBytes) throws Exception {
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signature.initVerify(publicKey);
        processData(fileToVerify, signature);
        return signature.verify(signatureBytes);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RSASignatureExample example = new RSASignatureExample();
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("rsa", null);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        fos.write("Hello World".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        fos.close();

        // Sign the file

        byte [] signatureBytes = example.sign(tempFile);

        // Verify the signature

        boolean isVerified = example.verify(tempFile, signatureBytes);
        System.out.printf("Signature verified ?: %b", isVerified);
    }
}
```